Unable to Connect to WebSocket Server with Self-Signed Certificate in Android using OkHttp
I'm trying to connect to a WebSocket server using OkHttp in an Android application. The server uses a self-signed certificate. While I can successfully connect to the server using wscat from the command line, my Android app fails to connect.
Here's my server setup using Vert.x and the client code in Android:
Server Code (Vert.x)
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;

public class App {
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(new VertxSocket());
    }
}


VertxSocket.java:
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerOptions;
import io.vertx.core.net.PfxOptions;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.core.eventbus.EventBus;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class VertxSocket extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Jaydeep\\Desktop\\key\\keystore.p12");
        String keystorePath = path.toAbsolutePath().toString();
        System.out.println(keystorePath);
        
        HttpServerOptions options = new HttpServerOptions()
            .setSsl(true)
            .setPfxKeyCertOptions(new PfxOptions()
                .setPath(keystorePath)
                .setPassword("123"));

        HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer(options);
        EventBus eventBus = vertx.eventBus();

        server.webSocketHandler(webSocket -> {
            System.out.println("Connected!");

            // Handle incoming messages
            webSocket.handler(data -> {
                System.out.println(data);
                JsonObject message = data.toJsonObject();
                String event = message.getString("event");
                JsonObject payload = message.getJsonObject("payload");


                eventBus.publish(event, payload);

                webSocket.writeFinalTextFrame(data.toString());
            });

            webSocket.closeHandler(v -> {
                System.out.println("Disconnected!");
            });

            
            webSocket.exceptionHandler(throwable -> {
                System.out.println("Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
            });
        }).listen(8080, res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("Server is now listening on port 8080!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to bind!");
                res.cause().printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        // Register handlers for the events on the Event Bus
        eventBus.consumer("OnPawnMove", message -> {
            JsonObject payload = (JsonObject) message.body();
            handlePawnMove(payload);
        });

        eventBus.consumer("OnDiceRoll", message -> {
            JsonObject payload = (JsonObject) message.body();
            handleDiceRoll(payload);
        });
    }

    private void handlePawnMove(JsonObject payload) {
        System.out.println("Pawn moved to: " + payload.encode());
     
    }

    private void handleDiceRoll(JsonObject payload) {
        System.out.println("Dice rolled: " + payload.encode());
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(new VertxSocket());
    }
}


Android Client Code
MainActivity.java:
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            WebSocketHelper webSocketHelper = new WebSocketHelper(this);
            webSocketHelper.connectWebSocket();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}


WebSocketHelper.java:
package com.example.imagemovement.sslconnect;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.imagemovement.R;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.WebSocket;
import okhttp3.WebSocketListener;
import okio.ByteString;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class WebSocketHelper {

    private static final String TAG ="WebSocketHelper" ;
    private Context context;

    public WebSocketHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void connectWebSocket() {
        try {
            // Load CA certificate
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ca);
            Certificate ca;
            try {
                ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            } finally {
                caInput.close();
            }

            // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            InputStream keyInputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

            // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(keyStore);

            // Load client certificate and key
            InputStream crtInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.crt);
            Certificate crt = cf.generateCertificate(crtInput);
            crtInput.close();

            InputStream keyInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.key);
            // Assuming the key is in PKCS#8 format
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            kmf.init(keyStore, "123".toCharArray()); // Use the password you used to generate the key

            // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

            // Create OkHttpClient and configure it to use the SSLContext
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0])
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder().url("wss://www.wslphone.com:8080").build();
            WebSocketListener listener = new WebSocketListener() {
                @Override
                public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
                    webSocket.send("hi");
                }

                @Override
                public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Received: " + text);
                }

                @Override
                public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Received bytes: " + bytes.hex());
                }

                @Override
                public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
                    webSocket.close(1000, null);
                    Log.d(TAG,"Closing: " + code + " / " + reason);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG,t.toString());
                }
            };

            WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
            client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "WebsocktHelper: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}


I have used same certificate and key which I used to generate keystore.p12 file In the Android Project However I am getting this error:
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.wslphone.com": No address associated with hostname
I have used www.wslphone.com as my domain while creating self signed certificate
I have able to connect to server using wscat:
C:\Users\Jaydeep>wscat -c wss://www.wslphone.com:8080 --key C:\Users\Jaydeep\Desktop\key\key.key --cert C:\Users\Jaydeep\Desktop\key\crt.crt --ca C:\Users\Jaydeep\Desktop\key\ca.pem
Connected (press CTRL+C to quit)

hi
Disconnected (code: 1006, reason: "")

I am trying to connect to a server using wss:

Server is created uisng vertx java, for wss I have used self signed certificate.
I am trying to connect my android app using Okhttps3 howere I am unable to connect to ther server and I am getting this error:java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.wslphone.com": No address associated with hostname

I am expecting to connect to my server using self signed certificate from my android app.
I am able to connect with just ws but my goal is to connect using wss

I have solved this , theproblem is not with the code but with the domain www.wslphone.com since I have create a self signed certificate and I have not bought the domain the domain only exist in my windows machine host file and I my the domain to my windows local ip however the Android Emulator has it own host file and that host file has not configured for the domain www.wslphone.com so I configure that in emulator hosts file and it worked
